# Python Code for Finding Specific Parameters

Tags: python

Project I've been working on for some time. It's working with ACLs, unfortunately the nature of the beast is disclosure is not possible so I'm going to provide as much detail as I can without giving anything away. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I was insistent on finding the solution myself but I'm afraid that I just do not know enough Python to achieve the desired result. I've achieved this result in batch, PowerShell, and even Bash... It's just not working out in a fast pace over network paths, not like our other Python scripts which buffer in memory first that work fast and smooth. Mind you this is going to sift through upwards 500K-5M rows of data.

**sampledata.csv**

```
GROUPS,PATH,EXPLICIT,STUFF
Group1,folder0,Explicit,somestuffhere
Group2,folder0,Explicit,somestuffhere
Group1,folder0\coolbeans,Implicit,somestuffhere
Group2,folder0\coolbeans,Implicit,Somestuffhere
Group3,folder0\coolbeans\awesomesauce,Implicit,Somestuffhere
Group3,folder1,Explicit,Somestuffhere
Group4,folder1\awesome,Implicit,Somestuffhere
Group5,folder1\awesome,Implicit,Somestuffhere
```

The concept:

- Generate a list of every Group where Explicit is present.
- Generate a list of every Group where Implicit is present.
- Both lists unique only (remove duplicates)
- Compare Both lists, for Group in Implicit that is not in Explicit.
- Filter the entire file content by the remaining group:
- Output each row with the Remaining Group entire row to a single file.

The Theory:

- Finding Microsoft's Move-to-Network(drag and drop) Folder inheritance issue.

I know that this will not just help myself but many others seeking out this challenge as well.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Additional Notes: Python Version 2.6.6

Per the Admins requesting an example of code I previously worked with: As previously stated.

```
    import csv
    import sys
    global exp
    global imp
    exp = set()
    imp = set()
    exc = set()
    i = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
    csvr = csv.reader(i)

    def expparse(target):
        if "Explicit" in target:
            exp.add(target[0])

    def impparse(target):
        if "Implicit" in target:
            imp.add(target[0])


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        for rows in csvr:
            expparse(rows)
            impparse(rows)

    exc = imp - exp # added with aid of Joran - Lack of knowledge to compare 2 Sets.
    for rows in (exc):
        print rows # Produces the right information, how do I set it as a filter?
```

As of yet, I'm still unsure how to now compare the exception from the entire CSV. My intent was to see what type of code others would produce unbiased. I wanted to see what others with more python experience had in mind, if that makes sense by leaving it unbiased.

How do in turn, get python to grab every line that matches lines in the exc set?

Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far that didnt work? and why didnt it work(eg. you expected this but got that other thing)?

Comment: Note that a statement that you tried isn't sufficient, even if it is believable. You need to show what *step* of what you're doing that you're stuck on.

Comment: Updated with code. added the line from Joran but I dont think that the method I took will be compatible with Hugh's output. His solution as a whole works, I just dont understand the itervalues and join method. Like, I'm unclear as to why the results, while valid, are reverse order of the csv file... or the test file I'm working on, it only outputs the first value that matches and ignores the rest. I would like to know how to in turn take what I have so far, and output for each line that matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
groups_explicit,groups_implicit = set(),set)_
with open(some_csv) as f:
    for line in f:
        if "Explicit" in line:
           groups_explicit.add(line.split(",",1)[0]) 
        elif "Implicit" in line:
           else groups_implicit.add(line.split(",",1)[0])
# use set difference to tell which groups are in implicit but not explicit
implicit_groups_not_in_explicit = groups_implicit - groups_explicit
```

might be what you are looking for ... its hard to tell

Comment: I had to modify the format somewhat, That helps get the implicit list, however I still have to grab every line from the main file that matches the result. You're right on the money though. Had to do some tweaking for 2.6.6.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
from itertools import izip, tee

INPUT = "some.csv"
OUTPUT = "filtered.csv"

implicit_groups = dict()
explicit_groups = set()

with open(INPUT, "rb") as inf:
    lines, to_rows = tee(inf)
    rows = csv.reader(to_rows)
    for line, row in izip(lines, rows):
        group, _, state, _ = row
        if state == "Explicit":
            implicit_groups.pop(group, None)
            explicit_groups.add(group)
        elif state == "Implicit":
            if group not in explicit_groups:
                implicit_groups[group] = line

with open(OUTPUT, "wb") as outf:
    # edit!  writing lines, not rows:
    outf.write("\n".join(implicit_groups.itervalues()))
```